# safe integer conversion in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a simple integer range checker and converter using c++ templates.
The code looks like this:

```
// D is the "destination" type and S the "source" type
template <class D, class S>
inline D SafeConvert( S value );

template <class S>
inline int SafeConvert<int>( S value ) {

    ASSERT( value >= S(INT_MIN) && value <= S(INT_MAX) );
    return int(value);
} /// error C2768: 'SafeConvert' : illegal use of explicit template arguments


template <class S>
inline size_t SafeConvert<size_t>( S value ) {

    ASSERT( value >= S(0) && value <= S(size_t(-1)) );
    return size_t(value);
} /// error C2768: 'SafeConvert' : illegal use of explicit template arguments


// ...

void test() {

    size_t v = INT_MAX+1;
    int iv = SafeConvert<int>(v);
}
```

However I have the following come compilation errors:

```
error C2768: 'SafeConvert' : illegal use of explicit template arguments
```

My question is how to tell the compiler that I want to specialize only the D class ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998571/c-template-for-safe-integer-casts/998982#998982

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't partially specialize function templates.  You need to mimic it with a class wrapper or use standard function overloading.  An example of mimicing:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct processor;

template < typename T1, typename T2 >
T1 fun(T2 t2) { return processor<T1,T2>::apply(t2); }

template < typename T2 >
struct processor<int,T2>
{
   static int apply(T2 t2) { .... }
};

...etc...
```

Answer (score 4):

It's going to be a bother, and a hell to maintain.

Normally I would advise using the `numeric_limits`:

```
template <class D, class S>
D SafeConvert(S value)
{
  ASSERT(value >= std::numeric_limits<D>::min()
      && value <= std::numeric_limits<D>::max());
  return static_cast<D>(value);
}
```

However there is a warning emitted by the compiler whenever you compare a signed integer with an unsigned one... (never really understood this by the way)

So, instead of reinventing the wheel, I shall advise the use of [Boost.NumericConversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html) and notably: `boost::numeric_cast<>`.

It's guaranteed to be performance free when the check is not required (ie the destination type is bigger than the source type) and otherwise perform the necessary checks.

Comment: Numeric limits and boost::numeric_cast is the way to go.

Comment: Does that assert work both in situations where the max of S is bigger and when the max of D is bigger? Or will implicit conversions screw it up in one direction?

Comment: @JosephGarvin: I am pretty confident that `boost::numeric_cast` works ;) For the custom solution presented here, I am afraid I don't know the implicit conversions by heart.

Answer (score 1):

Write a structure `SafeConverter<T, S>` that is used by `SafeConvert`. Better than partial specialization would be using `std::numeric_limits`, or even `boost::numeric_cast`, which already implements range checking in a more sophisticated way.

The latter could be implemented as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
struct numeric_converter {
  static T convert(const S& val);
}
template<typename T, typename S>
T numeric_cast(const S& val) {
  typedef numeric_converter<T, S> converter;
  return converter::convert(val);
}
```

Comment: I won't neg since I almost said the same thing but you should have checked your answer first.  Then you might have remembered why you can't do it that way.

Comment: the problem with SO is that the answers pop up way too fast so that I usually have no time to think about my answer before posting, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `SafeConvert<size_t, S>` instead of `SafeConvert<size_t>`, I think, to specialise only the second parameter. Noah Roberts is correct, too, on the point of partial specialisation of functions versus types.

Comment: Other way round; you want to specialise the first (destination) argument.