# Detecting integer truncation

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect integer overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/best-way-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

What is the best way to detect if integer truncation occurred?
**Edit**
This should cause truncation being signalled but it doesn't

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
typedef signed int int32_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef signed short int16_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;


int32_t my32bitInt = 0xffffffff;

int32_t tmp = my32bitInt & 0xFFFF8000;

uint16_t ss = my32bitInt;

int main()
{

    if (tmp != 0xFFFF8000 && tmp != 0x00000000)
    { // cannot be converted safely 
        cout << "truncation";
    }
        cout << ss << '\n';
    cout << my32bitInt << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
template <typename U, typename T>
bool is_safe(T t)
{
    return sizeof(U) <= sizeof(T) ? 
    (t >= static_cast<T>(std::numeric_limits<U>::min()))
        && (t <= static_cast<T>(std::numeric_limits<U>::max())) : true;
}
```

**Edit 3 (Based on Oli's <>) - I found some problems, but working on it, will update asap**

template 
bool is_safe(Source value)
{

```
if (sizeof(Result) == sizeof(Source))
{/*Same size*/

    if (std::is_same<Source,Result>::value)
    {
        //signed to signed or unsigned to unsigned when size is same - no problem
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //MSB mustn't be set in Source
        return !(value & (1u << ((sizeof(Source) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)));
    }
}
else
{//smaller to larger and larger to smaller

    if (sizeof(Result) <= sizeof(Source))
    { //Larger to smaller and both equal
        return ((value >= static_cast<Source>(std::numeric_limits<Result>::min()))
                && (value <= static_cast<Source>(std::numeric_limits<Result>::max())));
    }
    else
    { //smaller to larger

        if (std::is_signed<Source>::value && !std::is_signed<Result>::value)
        {
            //signed to unsigned - signed must be positive
            return (value >= 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by "truncation"? overflow?

Comment: I thought I saw this question earlier this week, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Maybe 'integer truncation' is integer overflow e.g. on addition. Or maybe loss of data when converting to a narrower type?

Comment: Follow up: Google is telling me that integer truncation can mean converting a fractional type to an adjacent integer, e.g. 3.21 to 3

Comment: @All Integer truncation != integer overflow.

Comment: Care to explain the difference, then? And what you define "integer truncation" as? Obviously people aren't sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Cody yes I care, integer truncation can occur when assigning larger type to smaller. And I would like you to note that it isn't me who "defines" as such integer truncation.

Comment: @There: That is a type of overflow, specifically resulting from a narrowing conversion.

Comment: @Potatoswatter if truncation is a type of overflow which more precisely describes action/effect that it is more appropriate to use more precise word. So if truncation is form of overflow but overflow is not form of truncation then if you/I/one thinks about specific case (truncation) then overflow is to wide and instead truncation (word) should be used.

Comment: @There: Except I've never heard the term "truncation" used that way. How is overflow resulting from addition *not* "truncation"?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "In mathematics and computer science, truncation is the term for limiting the number of digits right of the decimal point, by discarding the least significant ones."

Comment: When using signed numbers 0xFFFFFFFF is the same as -1, which can be converted to a smaller signed value. Hence, the code is correct. (Well, as long as you assume the signed integers are represented using two-complement. In general, try to avoid mixing signed integers and bit operations.)

Comment: @all_voters_to_close WHAT'S WRONG WITH THIS Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the value is the same after the assignment.

```
smallInt = largeInt;

if (smallInt != largeInt)
{
  // Truncation
}
```

Or, you could check with a mask before:

```
if (my32bitInt & 0xFFFF0000)
{
  // Can't be assigned to a 16 bit value.
}
```

Comment: @Lindydancer yep, that's the solution (the second one) I was hoping for. Funny though how many people (those who either voted to close or posted dummy comments) don't see difference between overflow and truncation. Thanks again.

Comment: That second method won't work with negative numbers (assuming two's complement).

Comment: @Lindydancer correct me if I'm wrong but your solution (the second one) works only on positive numbers isn't that so?

Comment: @Lindy what I'm looking for is some bitwise "trick" which would allow me to do this check (on signed and unsigned)

Comment: @There: `int32_t tmp = my32bitInt & 0xFFFF8000; if (tmp != 0xFFFF8000 && tmp != 0x00000000) { // cannot be converted safely }`.

Comment: @Oli by cannot be converted safely you mean "truncation will occur"? And if so on what basis does it work?

Comment: @There: Indeed, "unsafe" as in "truncation will occur".  This method is assuming two's-complement (which is pretty likely); it's checking that the first significant bit (i.e. first bit that isn't a sign bit) doesn't fall in a position that would be discarded.

Comment: @Oli would it be fair to say that your method could fail if assigning int32_t to int16_t?

Comment: @There: It's for exactly that purpose (change the constants and types as appropriate for a different mix of source and destination types).  So if there's a failure-case, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: @Oli if you do this: int32_t my32bitInt = 0xffffffff; uint16_t ss = my32bitInt; your code won't signal that truncation will occur.

Comment: @Oli I've edited (adding your method) my OP

Comment: @There: Yeah, I've written it assuming signed -> signed.  Obviously it needs a little modification if the destination type is unsigned.

Comment: @Oli but even if it is s to s it doesn't catch it.

Comment: @There: Give me an example where it doesn't?  (for e.g. int32_t to int16_t).

Comment: @Oli just change the type of my32bitInt;

Comment: @There: If I do that, then you're doing unsigned -> unsigned, which isn't what I had in mind...  Anyway, see the answer I've added.

Comment: This doesn't work. Consider: `unsigned int x = -1;`. Comparing `x` against `-1` will yield true. Still the value of `x` is not `-1`, but `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 4):

See [Boost Numeric Conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html), specifically [`numeric_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html).

Comment: +1 Sweet!  I didn't know that existed.  That's my answer, but done properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ programmer but i think you should do something like this:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{

    float number = 0.001;
    if ((int) number == number)
    {

        cout << "Hello world";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that is a correct solution.

Comment: I can't see any good reason (length of code, copyright on code, etc) to have the code not be in the answer, so I've copied it into the answer.

Comment: Thank u! It's just that i've already had written it there, cause i didn't have a compiler on my machine :D.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check without doing the conversion, in a type-safe manner, how about the following:

```
template <typename U, typename T>
bool is_safe(T t)
{
    return (t >= (T)std::numeric_limits<U>::min())
        && (t <= (T)std::numeric_limits<U>::max());
}

int main()
{
    int32_t a = -32768;
    int32_t b = +32768;
    int32_t c = +32767;
    int32_t d = -32769;
    std::cout << is_safe<int16_t>(a) << std::endl;  // 1
    std::cout << is_safe<int16_t>(b) << std::endl;  // 0
    std::cout << is_safe<int16_t>(c) << std::endl;  // 1
    std::cout << is_safe<int16_t>(d) << std::endl;  // 0
}
```

Obviously this will break if `U` is a bigger type than `T`, but I'm sure it could be adapted.

Comment: what about this ... check my edit.

Comment: @There: That indeed catches most cases.  However, one case I can think of is if e.g. `T` is `int16_t` and `U` is `uint16_t`.  But I bet with a bit more work, things like that can be solved.  Of course, the easiest thing to do is simply to use @LindyDancer's original test.

Comment: I just wonder what is the performance cost between doing the let's say lindy's method and fancy template checking. Because if lindy's is more efficient there is really little point of doing the whole sophisticated "templated" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to check it before doing the conversion. [These templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998571/c-template-for-safe-integer-casts/998982#998982) do exactly that. Example:

```
/* unsigned -> signed, overflow */
safe_cast<short>(UINT_MAX);

/* unsigned -> unsigned, overflow */
safe_cast<unsigned char>(ULONG_MAX);

/* signed -> unsigned, overflow */
safe_cast<unsigned long>(-1);

/* signed -> signed, overflow */
safe_cast<signed char>(INT_MAX);

/* always works (no check done) */
safe_cast<long>(INT_MAX);

// giving these assertion failures results
(type)f <= (type)is_signed<To>::v_max
f <= (To)-1
f >= 0
f >= is_signed<To>::v_min && f <= is_signed<To>::v_max
```

Comment: I've "improved" Oli's <> (see Edit 3) so I think it covers every case and it's "bit" less complicated than your solution (although excellent). I wonder what you think of my approach?