# Safely convert SIZE_T to WORD

Tags: c, winapi, type-conversion

In my C code, I want to convert `SIZE_T` `WINAPI` type, in either 32/64 bit system to a `WORD` `WINAPI` type.

```
#include <Windows.h>
SIZE_T nValueToConvert;
WORD wConvertedValue;
```

In case that `nValueToConvert` is too big for `WORD` type I want to know abot it and raise an error. What is the best and safest way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Template for safe integer casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998571/c-template-for-safe-integer-casts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exist many ways do this. for example we can use next code:

```
if ((wConvertedValue = (WORD)nValueToConvert) == nValueToConvert)
{
    DbgPrint("convert ok\n");
}
else
{
    DbgPrint("too big for WORD\n");
}
```

---

however this is valid only for **unsigned** types - both `SIZE_T` and `WORD` is unsigned. if work with **signed** types, say `SSIZE_T nValueToConvert` and `SHORT wConvertedValue`, task become more complex, separate signed bit create problems here. i think try truncate and check can be done next way:

```
BOOL Truncate(SSIZE_T nValueToConvert, SHORT* pwConvertedValue)
{
    SHORT wConvertedValue;

    if (0 > nValueToConvert)
    {
        wConvertedValue = -(wConvertedValue = ((SHORT)-nValueToConvert));
    }
    else
    {
        wConvertedValue = (SHORT)nValueToConvert;
    }

    *pwConvertedValue = wConvertedValue;

    return wConvertedValue == nValueToConvert;
}
```

`Truncate` return true when `SSIZE_T nValueToConvert` in range `[-0x8000, 0x7FFF]`, otherwise false

Answer (score 1):

Conversion may not give a proper result. The type sizes are different. Check this:

[Window Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

`SIZE_T` Unsigned integral type; defined as:

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;
```

`WORD`   A 16-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 65535 decimal.
This type is declared in *WinDef.h* as follows:

```
  typedef unsigned short WORD;
```

But if you really want to compare them than

```
if( nValueToConvert > 65535 ) (
{
    DbgPrint("Conversion is not safe\n");
}
else
{
    DbgPrint("conversion is OK\n");
}
```

Comment: Why would this conversion _never_ be safe? [When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p1).

Comment: @DavidBowling You are right.! By save I meant a proper result of conversion. For example `unsigned int` cannot be properly converted to `unsigned char` we will loose a precision.

Comment: Any integer value in the range of an `unsigned char` can be converted to an `unsigned char` value with the value unchanged.

Comment: @DavidBowling You are right!  I mess up. Correcting my answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you!